How to replace body for specific query response in Network Profiler Rule?
I have created a rule for specific queries in Android Studio Network Profiler, where I try to substitute the status code (from 200 to 401) as well as the response body from the expected one to:
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token expired: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cC...”
}

The problem is that while I see in the Network Profiler that the response code has been substituted, the body doesn't (I am getting an empty body instead of error one).


And the response I get is:

The question is - what am I missing here? Why body isn't appearing?
